# PHPUnit - Testing Switch/Default cases

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a question about PHPUnit. I want to write a test case for the following *`Message`* class and want to cover the *`default: case`* in my test cases by passing an invalid *`$type`* in the `isValidMessageType()` method. Just to give you a proper scenario of when this will be useful, suppose the developer adds another type i.e. 3 in the `isValidMessageType()` method but forgets to add a switch case in the `SendMessage()` method, in that scenario the default case will throw an exception.

```
class Message
{

    public function isValidMessageType($type)
    {
        return ($type == 1 || $type == 2)
    }

    public function SendMessage($type)
    {

        if(!$this->isValidMessageType($type)){
            throw new Exception('Invalid Message type');
        }

        switch ($type) {
            case 1:
                // do something
                break;
            case 2:
                // do something
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception('Invalid Message type');
        }

    }

}
```

Can someone please help me how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will test for the results from isValidMessageType of TRUE/FALSE, and then will test for a return value from SendMEssage().  However, you need to return something from SendMessage() or have something that can be tested, to truly test the code.

```
class Message_TEST extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $TestObject;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->TestObject = new Message();
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
    }

    public function testisValidMessageType()
    {
        $this->assertTrue($this->TestObject->isValidMessageType(1));
        $this->assertTrue($this->TestObject->isValidMessageType(2));

        $this->assertFalse($this->TestObject->isValidMessageType(3));
        $this->assertFalse($this->TestObject->isValidMessageType('A'));
    }

    /**
     * @expectedException \Exception
     */
    public function testSendMessageException()
    {
        $this->TestObject->isValidMessageType(3);
    }

    public function testSendMessage()
    {
        $this->assertEquals('Need Return from SendMessage', $this->TestObject->SendMessage(1));
        $this->assertEquals('Need Return from SendMessage', $this->TestObject->SendMessage(2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have duplicated the logic for determining if a $type is correct or not. First you check it with the **isValidMessageType** method, but then you check it again at the default case.

You should not write code you don't need. Just make sure that if you pass an invalid $type an Exception will be thrown. You only need to do that once. You can get rid of the **isValidMessageType** method and the system will work as expected.

Comment: I have another offtopic question, Suppose I have a method GetUserDetails() in the class "User", and there are 10 possible test cases, should I be adding all those 10 test cases in the testGetUserDetails() method in the UserTest class or do I write each cases in separate methods like testGetUserDetailsCaseA(), testGetUserDetailsCaseB(), testGetUserDetailsCaseC() etc etc??

Comment: I suggest resolving this answer and opening a new one. So everybody will read it.

Answer (score 1):

I find using "phpunit --coverage-html outputdir --debug" and checking the report (index.html in outputdir) is useful at times like this, to see where tests are going.

BTW Each test should test one thing only, otherwise when a test fails you will spend extra time debugging your test as well as your code. Consider revising as below. You can cut down on the repetition by only testing one 'good' value and one 'bad' value if you wish, unless you specifically need to test more cases.

```
public function testOneisValidMessageType()
{
    $this->assertTrue($this->TestObject->isValidMessageType(1));
}

public function testTwoisValidMessageType()
{
    $this->assertTrue($this->TestObject->isValidMessageType(2));
}

public function testThreeisNotValidMessageType()
{
    $this->assertFalse($this->TestObject->isValidMessageType(3));
}

public function testStringisNotValidMessageType()
{
    $this->assertFalse($this->TestObject->isValidMessageType('A'));
}
```